# Due to problems with Time Machine, I've switched to Backblaze as my backup. Is this as useful as Time Machine?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I encountered a problem with Time Machine and it has stopped working. I tried the suggested repair path but it didn't work. I have turned off Time Machine and switched to Backblaze as my backup option. If anyone is using BackBlaze or another 3rd party backup plan I am curious how it compares to Time Machine in terms of usefulness and is there anything I should be aware of.

Comment: I'd flip your boot drive back to HFS+ & your TM issues will vanish. Personally, I consider BB to be the braces for a full 'belt & braces' backup strategy.

Comment: @Tetsujin My iMac is pretty old (2010) but has never given me a serious problem.  I'm a little reluctant to try your suggestion but it appears to be the only answer to my problems.  Can you recommend a site that has fairly simple instructions on how to clone the startup volume and how to reload it?  I'm not a newbie but I haven't attempted this before.

Comment: I use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) - it's pretty much click, click, click, wait... done. Others exist that I've heard are good, but I've never used them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you cannot use if for a system restore or getting files versioned earlier in time. It is often worth it to resolve the time machine issues instead.

Backblaze itself is a wonderful effective offsite backup solution, and I often recommend such a service as a fallback to timemachine.

Comment: Backblaze will 'version' - though relatively crudely, simply by date.

Comment: By date is fine. I was backing up only once a week.